# How can I programmatically uninstall my MSIX python app?

Tags: python, wix, pyinstaller, uninstallation, msix

I've just written my first MSIX app in python 3. I use [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) to generate an EXE. Then I use [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/) to generate an MSI. I then use [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/tool-overview) to create the MSIX. There's probably an easier way to go from code to MSIX, but that's what I've gotten to work so far.

Ideally, I'd like to capture an onuninstall event and throw a GUI prompt asking the user why they are uninstalling. I can do this in the MSI. However, my understanding is that [MSIX offers no onuninstall event](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/16). Please let me know if you know differently!

Since I apparently can't catch the MSIX uninstall event, my next preference is to offer the user a way to uninstall the app from the tray icon. The user selects an uninstall tray menu button from my app's icon, which pops up a window where the app then asks them why they are uninstalling. They type in an answer, and then click the submit button. Then, the app should completely uninstall itself. This also works well in the MSI. However, I can't get it to work in the MSIX.

Here's what works in python with the MSI installed:

```
subprocess.call('msiexec.exe /x {' + myguid + '}', shell=True)
```

However, the MSIX, which is built from the MSI, throws this popup error message when that line runs, and never actually uninstalls the app:

```
This action is only valid for products that are currently installed.
```

I've tried using the GUID from my WXS file's `<Product>` entry, hard-coded, just to see if it would work. That one worked for uninstalling the MSI, but not the MSIX. I also tried getting the GUID dynamically, but that didn't work for either MSI or MSIX, both producing the same error as above. Here is how I got the GUID dynamically:

```
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal
from System import Reflection

myguid = str(Marshal.GetTypeLibGuidForAssembly(
    Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
)).upper()
```

While running the MSI (where I have far better logging than in the MSIX), it appears as though `GetExecutingAssembly()` gets an assembly with a `FullName` of `Python.Runtime`, which is certainly something I don't want to uninstall. `GetCallingAssembly()` produces the same result. `GetEntryAssembly()` produces a `null` value.

I looped through `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to see what was listed and my app was not listed, though I saw many libraries that it uses.

So, any thoughts on how I can get the app to programmatically uninstall? Maybe a suggestion on how I can get the correct GUID for the MSIX app, if that's the problem? DotNet code should be fine. I can probably figure out how to translate it to python.

Or better yet, any idea how I can catch the MSIX uninstall event and run some custom code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know at this moment catching the uninstall event is not possible. I don't recommend implementing the approach you suggested (the tray icon) but to ask your question, you can use the [MSIX PowerShell commandlets](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-powershell-cmdlets.html) to install and uninstall MSIX packages programmatically.

Also, I noticed you are really torturing yourself to create the MSIX package.

The MSIX Packaging Tool was created by Microsoft for IT professionals that don't have access to the source code. Developers can either use the Windows Application Packaging Project project template (if they use Visual Studio) or other third-party tools, like Advanced Installer or Wix (from what I know there was a [Wix extension that can be used to build MSIX packages](https://www.firegiant.com/products/wix-expansion-pack/msix/)).

Here is a quick tutorial on how to create an MSIX from scratch, easier with Advanced Installer:
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/create-msi-python-executable.html

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: Thanks! I tried the WiX MSIX process previously and couldn't get it to work for me. If I recall correctly, WiX MSIX also only works for a Visual Studio project, and I'm not using Visual Studio at all. I suspect Advanced Installer would make things much easier, but I'm trying to accomplish this without spending any additional $$. I'll check out the commandlets though!

Answer (score 0):

I used Bogdan's Powershell suggestion and came up with the following code, which seems to work well:

```
import subprocess

powershellLocation = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
try:
    # Use the name of the app (which I found manually using Get-AppPackage)
    # to get the full name of the app, which seems to have some random numbers
    # on the end of it.
    powershell_tuple = subprocess.Popen([
        powershellLocation,
        "Get-AppPackage",
        "-name",
        '"' + myAppPackageName + '"'
    ],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    appStrings = powershell_tuple[0].decode('utf-8').strip()
except Exception as e:
    pass
for appStr in appStrings.splitlines():
    # Find the full name of the app
    if appStr.startswith('PackageFullName'):
        colonIndex = appStr.index(':') + 1
        fullName = appStr[colonIndex:].strip()
if fullName:
    # The MSIX package was found, and I now have its full name
    subprocess.call(powershellLocation + ' Remove-AppPackage -Package "' + fullName + '"', shell=True)
```